# How did you set up your DNS records for an Azure Cloud Application

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers, cname, azure

I would like some advice.

I want to be able to have my zone apex and also www point to a cloud application that is running on Azure.

Should I use:

```
           CNAME    www.xx.com >  xx.cloud.net
           CNAME -      xx.com >  xx.cloud.net
```

or

```
           A        www.xx.com > 123.456.789
           A            xx.com > 123.456.789
```

or

```
           A            xx.com > 123.456.789
           CNAME    www.xx.com > xx.com
```

I'm very confused now over which is best. Low latency is important for me but I am also concerned if the IP address of the cloud application was to change.

Has anyone any experience with setting this up for an azure application?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a CNAME for your root domain name in my opinion so I would go with your 2nd example.

```
   A            xx.com > 123.456.789
   A            www.xx.com > xx.com
```

Although it is debatable I would say to answer your question specifically, whilst on the same domain (i.e. subdomains) it would be perfectly fine to use a CNAME however in the case of Azure you would be pointing it to another domain would be incurring the extra dns lookup required and thus slow the time taken for the request to be completed.
Taking that into consideration, your 3rd example would be perfectly fine as well.

```
   A            xx.com > 123.456.789
   CNAME        www.xx.com > xx.com
```

Some large websites seem to mainly use A records so I would probably stick to those unless you are planning on changing IPs often.

Comment: To clarify the reason -- using a CNAME for the root breaks MX records: http://serverfault.com/questions/91712/dns-using-cnames-breaks-mx-records